# remove custom taxonomy metabox form custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type 'hotel' and custom 'taxonomy' so when administrator creates a new hotel and saves it it related custom taxonomy automatically get created but I don't want to show custom metabox in the admin side hotel edit page so for that I used WordPress function   but nothing happen.

---

My custom post code

```
$Hotel_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Hotels', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Hotel', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Hotel'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add Hotel'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Hotel'),
    'new_item' => __('New Hotel'),
    'all_items' => __('All Hotels'),
    'view_item' => __('View Hotel'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Hotel'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Hotel found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Hotel found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Hotel'),
);



$Hotel_args = array(
    'labels' => $Hotel_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Hotel'),
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 100,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('hotel_facilities','package_hotel','post_tag')
);

register_post_type('Hotel',$Hotel_args);
```

---

### Custom taxonomy code

```
$Package_labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Package Hotels', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'hotel', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search hotels' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular hotels' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All hotels' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit hotel' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update hotel' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New hotel' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New hotel Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate hotels with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove hotels' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used hotels' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Package Hotels' ),
);

register_taxonomy('package_hotel','package',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $Package_labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'hotels' ),
));
```

---

### code to remove custom taxonomy metabox form custom post type hotel page

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('tagsdiv_hotels', 'Hotel', 'side');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `register_taxonomy()` : you have kept

```
'show_ui' => true,
```

change it to

```
'show_ui' => false,
```

this argument determines whether or not a user interface should be displayed to manage the taxonomy. As you don't want it, you have to set it to `false`.

Comment: Thanks barakadam 
I tried doing it what it does it remove my custom taxonomy from rest of the custom post types which I don't want I have gone throw [remove_meta_box($custom_taxonomy_slug.'div', $custom_post_type, 'side' );](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) in the end of the page it shows how to remove the custom metabox from custom post type by giving the slug of custom post type and custom taxonomy as an argument and I think I am not giving the arguments in right manner and that's what the problem is. is it ?

Comment: Maybe you are not doing it the right way. The taxonomy is "registered" for each post type. If you don't want to show it for a post type, you should just not register it for this post type. Now if your problem is to give different permissions to different people who have access to the admin, you should proceed differently and hide the taxonomy according to user levels, with a plug-in like  User Role Editor. You will find a corresponding capability like manage_categories, etc.

Comment: Barakadam my requirements is when a hotel post is created it title is saved in the form of tag in package_hotel custom taxonomy but I want it to be behind the seen so for that I have to register the custom taxonomy for custom post type hotel so that's my requirement

Comment: So are you saying all you want to do is that when a hotel post is saved, a taxonomy entry with the same name is created, but you actually do not need that taxonomy for the custom post type? Then don't do it this way ! Use save_post hook and wp_insert_term to trigger the creation of your taxonomy entry (taking the title as a parameter), and don't register the taxonomy for this custom post type at all !

Comment: ok thanks for the solution is it still work without registering the custom taxonomy for custom post type or what I want to ask is If I create both the custom taxonomy and post and I don't register custom taxonomy with custom post still wp_insert_term function will save a new term in that custom taxonomy ? I am side by side testing it but out of curiosity just asked this question.

Comment: wp_insert_term asks you to specify which taxonomy you want to insert your new term into.

Answer (score 7):

Since WordPress 3.8 version there is a `meta_box_cb` [argument available](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments). Just change this argument to `false` in your arguments definition so

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_in_menu'               => true,
    'meta_box_cb'                => false,
);
```

This will leave a sub-menu item under your custom post type but will remove a meta box on post edit page.

Answer (score 1):

> change meta box id `enter code here`
>
> function my_remove_meta_boxes() { remove_meta_box('package_hotel',
>   'Hotel', 'side'); } add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes'
>   );

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I tried changing the id but still it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now the example given in [Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) is like this

---

```
`remove_meta_box($custom_taxonomy_slug.'div', $custom_post_type, 'side' );`

    // $custom_taxonomy_slug is the slug of your taxonomy, e.g. 'genre' )
    // $custom_post_type is the "slug" of your post type, e.g. 'movies' )
```

---

which further directs to write syntax for metabox attribute in the function like this
`remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'custom_post_id', 'side' );`

---

and in my case the syntax for custom metabox attribute which worked is like this 
`remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-package_hotel', 'hotel', 'side');`
so instead of appending div at the end append tagsdiv_ in the begnning eg:- tagsdiv_$your_custom_taxonomy_id